# Checking Relative Path Trees in Batch Files

Tags: for-loop, variables, batch-file, automation

I'm working on a Fallout 4 weapon mod, and to increase my efficiency I am trying to automate the compression of my .tga textures to .dds files. I have most of it down but I'd like to automatically assign relative paths by comparing the relative path of the .tga files to the root path. As it stands I have the process automated for the receivers, and it works well. However the way I accomplished it would require way too many IF statements. I'd like to be able to assign the relative directory path of any given file to the .bat's directory as a variable so that the source folder structure is replicated.

My current .bat is as follows

```
@echo off

:Check
:: I CHECK IF THE PATHS ARE CORRECT
:: AND PREVIEW THE COMMAND TO COMPRESS 

:: CHECK FOR DIFFUSE MAPS TO BE ENCODED AS BC3 .DDS FILES
FOR /r %%i IN (*_d.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    :: I GET THE FULL PATH OF THE .TGA FILE
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    :: I LOCATE THE COMPRESSION PROGRAM 
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    :: I SPECIFY THE LOCATION OF MY WORKING .DDS FILES
    set "outputTexturePath= E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    :: I CAPTURE THE PARENT FOLDER OF THE .TGA FILE
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    :: HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK
    :: THE IF COMMANDS ARE TEMPORARY WORKAROUNDS
    :: FOR EXAMPLE ANY FILE IN THIS DIRECTORY'S "\Receivers\C7_Lower\" SUBDIR NEEDS TO BE SENT TO THE OUTPUT DIR'S  
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    :: I STRIP THE .TGA EXTENSION
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    :: I NOW COMPILE EVERYTHING FROM ABOVE TO GET
    set "fullOutputPath=!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!.dds"
    @echo !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" "!fullOutputPath!" -fd BC3  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
:: CHECK FOR NORMAL AND SPEC MAPS TO BE ENCODED AS BC5 .DDS FILES
FOR /r %%i IN (*_s.tga *_n.tga *_ndx.tga) DO (
    ::SAME LOGIC AS THE DIFFUSE MAPS
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"1
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath="E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath=!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!.dds"
    @echo !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" "!fullOutputPath!" -fd BC5  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
choice /M "Are paths correct?"
:: IF THE COMPRESSION COMMANDS HAVE THE RIGHT DESTINATIONS I PROCEED
if %errorlevel%==1 goto Continue
:: IF THEY DO NOT I SKIP THE COMPRESSION PROCESS TO AVOID WRITING TEXTURES TO THE WRONG DESTINATIONS
if %errorlevel%==2 goto Abort

:Continue
:: SAME PROCESS AS :Check BUT THE COMPRESSION COMMAND IS NOW RUN INSTEAD OF ECHOED
FOR /r %%i IN (*_d.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath=E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath="!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!".dds"
    !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" !fullOutputPath! -fd BC3  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
:: PROGRESS NOTIFICATION, WANT A PROGRESS BAR LATER
@echo BC3 files compressed!
FOR /r %%i IN (*_s.tga *_n.tga *_ndx.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath=E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath="!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!".dds"
    !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" !fullOutputPath! -fd BC5  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
:: PROGRESS NOTIFICATION, WANT A PROGRESS BAR LATER
@echo BC5 files Compressed!
:: ALL.TGA FILES HAVE NOW BEEN PROPERLY ENCODED 
goto :end

:Abort
:: NO COMPRESSION, PROCESS ABORTED
goto :end

:end
::END OF FILE
```

Or with REM

```
@echo off

:Check
REM I CHECK IF THE PATHS ARE CORRECT
REM AND PREVIEW THE COMMAND TO COMPRESS 

REM CHECK FOR DIFFUSE MAPS TO BE ENCODED AS BC3 .DDS FILES
FOR /r %%i IN (*_d.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM I GET THE FULL PATH OF THE .TGA FILE
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    REM I LOCATE THE COMPRESSION PROGRAM 
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    REM I SPECIFY THE LOCATION OF MY WORKING .DDS FILES
    set "outputTexturePath= E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    REM I CAPTURE THE PARENT FOLDER OF THE .TGA FILE
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    REM HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK
    REM THE IF COMMANDS ARE TEMPORARY WORKAROUNDS
    REM FOR EXAMPLE ANY FILE IN THIS DIRECTORY'S "\Receivers\C7_Lower\" SUBDIR NEEDS TO BE SENT TO THE OUTPUT DIR'S  
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    REM I STRIP THE .TGA EXTENSION
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    REM I NOW COMPILE EVERYTHING FROM ABOVE TO GET
    set "fullOutputPath=!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!.dds"
    @echo !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" "!fullOutputPath!" -fd BC3  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
REM CHECK FOR NORMAL AND SPEC MAPS TO BE ENCODED AS BC5 .DDS FILES
FOR /r %%i IN (*_s.tga *_n.tga *_ndx.tga) DO (
    REMSAME LOGIC AS THE DIFFUSE MAPS
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"1
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath="E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath=!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!.dds"
    @echo !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" "!fullOutputPath!" -fd BC5  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
choice /M "Are paths correct?"
REM IF THE COMPRESSION COMMANDS HAVE THE RIGHT DESTINATIONS I PROCEED
if %errorlevel%==1 goto Continue
REM IF THEY DO NOT I SKIP THE COMPRESSION PROCESS TO AVOID WRITING TEXTURES TO THE WRONG DESTINATIONS
if %errorlevel%==2 goto Abort

:Continue
REM SAME PROCESS AS :Check BUT THE COMPRESSION COMMAND IS NOW RUN INSTEAD OF ECHOED
FOR /r %%i IN (*_d.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath=E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath="!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!".dds"
    !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" !fullOutputPath! -fd BC3  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
REM PROGRESS NOTIFICATION, WANT A PROGRESS BAR LATER
@echo BC3 files compressed!
FOR /r %%i IN (*_s.tga *_n.tga *_ndx.tga) DO (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thisFilePath=%%~dpnxi"
    set "compressonatorCLIPath=C:\Compressonator_4.4.19\bin\CLI\compressonatorcli.exe"
    set "outputTexturePath=E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Fallout 4\Working\FROST_AR15_Canada\HiPoly\GameFileSystem\Textures\Cerebral\Diemaco_AR15\"
    for %%p in ("%%~dpi\.") do set "foundFileSubDir=%%~nxp\"
    if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
    set "thisFileName=%%~ni"
    set "fullOutputPath="!outputTexturePath!!thisFileSubDir!!thisFileName!".dds"
    !compressonatorCLIPath! "!thisFilePath!" !fullOutputPath! -fd BC5  -Quality 1.0000  -NumThreads 6 
    endlocal
)
REM PROGRESS NOTIFICATION, WANT A PROGRESS BAR LATER
@echo BC5 files Compressed!
REM ALL.TGA FILES HAVE NOW BEEN PROPERLY ENCODED 
goto :end

:Abort
REM NO COMPRESSION, PROCESS ABORTED
goto :end

:end
REM END OF FILE
```

The problem I am running into is that if statement:

```
if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C7_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else if "!foundFileSubDir!"=="C8_Lower\" (set "thisFileSubDir=Receivers\!foundFileSubDir!") else (set "thisFileSubDir=!foundFileSubDir!")
```

While it *works* it requires me to add additional if statements for every folder that isn't an immediate child of the .bat's parent folder.
The current structure is this:

```
Diemaco_AR15
├───Barrels
├───Handguards
├───Muzzles
├───Receivers
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_BufferTube_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_BufferTube_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_BufferTube_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_BufferTube_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_CarryHandle_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_CarryHandle_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_CarryHandle_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_CarryHandle_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_Bits_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_Bits_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_Bits_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_Bits_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_01_Upper_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_BufferTube_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_BufferTube_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_BufferTube_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_BufferTube_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_CarryHandle_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_CarryHandle_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_CarryHandle_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_CarryHandle_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_Bits_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_Bits_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_Bits_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_Bits_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_02_Upper_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_03_Rail_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_03_Rail_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_03_Rail_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_03_Rail_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_BufferTube_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_BufferTube_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_BufferTube_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_BufferTube_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Rail_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Rail_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Rail_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Rail_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_Bits_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_Bits_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_Bits_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_Bits_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_04_Upper_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_BufferTube_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_BufferTube_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_BufferTube_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_BufferTube_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Carbine_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Carbine_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Carbine_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Carbine_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Rifle_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Rifle_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Rifle_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_MonoRail_Rifle_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_Bits_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_Bits_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_Bits_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_Bits_s.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_d.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_n.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_ndx.tga
│   │   Diemaco_Receiver_05_Upper_s.tga
│   │
│   ├───C7_Lower
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_d.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_n.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_ndx.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_s.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_d.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_n.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_ndx.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_s.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_d.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_n.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_ndx.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_s.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_d.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_n.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_ndx.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_s.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_d.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_n.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_ndx.tga
│   │       Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_s.tga
│   │
│   └───C8_Lower
│           Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_d.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_n.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_ndx.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_s.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_d.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_n.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_ndx.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_02_Lower_s.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_d.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_n.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_ndx.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_03_Lower_s.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_d.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_n.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_ndx.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_04_Lower_s.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_d.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_n.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_ndx.tga
│           Diemaco_Receiver_05_Lower_s.tga
│
├───Sights
```

For `Diemaco_AR15\Receivers\C8_Lower\Diemaco_Receiver_01_Lower_d.tga` I don't want to check if the targa itself is in `Diemaco_AR15\Receivers\C8_Lower\` but rather check if `C8_Lower\` is in `Diemaco_AR15\`. If it isn't I need to append `Recievers\` to the `foundFileSubDir` variable. IE get the variable to be something more like `!foundFileMainDir!\!foundFileSubDir!\`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `::` is an (invalid) label. I know, it's often used as a comment and it works outside of code blocks (as in "ignore this line"), but it tends to do very unexpected things in a code block. Use the `REM`  command (as in "remark") instead.